# How to find out if a terminal supports UTF-8

Tags: terminal, utf-8

I'm setting up the CPAN module for perl on CentOs 5, and one of the questions is 'Does your terminal support UTF-8?' (paraphrased). How do I find out?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Really, the surefire way to test is to download a [text file](http://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/~mgk25/ucs/examples/) and cat it in the terminal and see if everything looks ok.

or, if you can, recompile the terminal enabling the unicode option (assuming it has one).

what does $TERM and $LANG look like?

Comment: $TERM is "xterm"  
$LANG is "en_US.UTF-8" (aha!)  
The text file displays nicely in terminal, but curiously, not in Firefox.

Comment: yea, i actually encountered the same thing :-/ ... when i tried therek's suggestion, i got the question mark

Comment: $LANG just tells you what your system will use when writing to stdout/stderr. It doesn't say anything about the capabilities of the terminal. However, if everything your system prints of weird characters looks ok, then your terminal probably supports UTF-8.

Comment: This can even be automated, by displaying some text and checking its width (by reading the cursor position before and after). I posted a [proof of concept](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/10698/timing-out-in-a-shell-script) a propos something else.

Comment: @Gilles, your answer is brilliantly simple. Love it!

Answer (score 27):

Type this in your terminal:

```
echo -e '\xe2\x82\xac'
```

If your terminal supports UTF-8 it will output the euro sign:

```
€
```

Comment: Not all fonts have the euro sign, so a different test code point might be advisable.

Answer (score 5):

The lamest way: run following and check the output. It will be a capital O with circumflex if the terminal displays UTF-8.

```
perl -le 'print "\x{c3}\x{94}"'
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure my terminal supports UTF-8 now (passed the test suggested by theman_on_osx) but this just outputs a blank line. What's going on?

Comment: Maybe the font you're using in your terminal app does not support UTF-8 characters.

Comment: I know this is extremely late but the UTF-8 Out flag makes that work better `perl -CO -le 'print "\x{d4}"'`

Comment: Or without the -CO option, give Perl the correct UTF-8 bytes :
  $ perl -le 'print "\x{c3}\x{94}"'
  Ô

Answer (score 2):

The most sure fire way is to use the ‘locale’ command.  It will print out all the various and sundry variables that dictate what character set to use.  For instance, this is my output on RHEL5.3, set to only use UTF-8 by default.

```
LANG="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=
```

Comment: This doesn't test the terminal, only the locale setting (which in practice isn't always set by the terminal emulator, may not reflect the current state of the terminal, or may have been overridden by some user configuration).

Answer (score 1):

You may just use the following command:

```
locale charmap
```

Comment: This doesn't test the terminal. It only displays the locale settings.

Answer (score 1):

```
curl http://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/~mgk25/ucs/examples/UTF-8-demo.txt
```

or

```
wget -O - http://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/~mgk25/ucs/examples/UTF-8-demo.txt
```

This obviously requires `wget` or `curl`.

Answer (score 0):

```
UTF=$(echo -e "\u263A")
if [[ ! "$UTF" =~ "A" ]]  ; then
 echo -n "UNICODE here!"
fi
```

Comment: This doesn't test the terminal. It only tests whether the `echo` builtin supports `\u`.

Answer (score 0):

You can test the terminal by setting the cursor position to column 1 and outputing a multibyte unicode character. If the cursor moves by more than 1 position then the terminal does not support unicode.

On in this case we emit a 3 byte sequence which is a zero width space, so if the cursor moves at all, the terminal cannot process unicode

```
IFS=$';\x1B[' read -p $'\r\xE2\x80\x8B\x1B[6n\r   \r' -d R -rst 1 _ _ _ X _ </dev/tty 2>/dev/tty && test "$X" = 1
```

Here we output `\r` to get to position 1 and then emit a 3 byte sequence which is a zero width space, and then emit `ESC [ 6n` which asks the cursor position, followed by `\r    \r` to overwrite any junk that will have appeared if the terminal handled each byte as a separate character.

Then we read the cusor position with a 1 second timeout and check whether the X position is position 1 which it will be if the terminal can process unicode.

A better function is:

```
is-tty-unicode() {
  local X

  test -c /dev/tty &&
  if test -t 0
  then IFS=$';\x1B[' read -p $'\r\xE2\x80\x8B\x1B[6n\r   \r' -d R -rst 1 _ _ _ X _ 2>&1
  fi <>/dev/tty && test "$X" = 1
}
```